# change the background color of particular time slot in DHTMLX scheduler

Tags: dhtmlx

In Dhtmlx Scheduler, I want to change the background color of particular time slot, e.g 1PM to 2PM, provided that this is not an 'event'. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using the `scheduler.markTimespan` method.

See the documentation [here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxscheduler%3aapi_method_dhtmlxscheduler_marktimespan).